# Excel - Create new rows based on drop down value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I want to create a table in excel for an investment calculator that adds rows in based on a drop down value.

i.e. If the user only wishes to see an investment plan for 5 years they select 5 years from the drop down menu and only 5 rows are generated. How do I achieve this? (If this is even possible)

**In response to K.Davis's comment:** 
I have tried to adapt your code and change the cells where needed however the code still doesn't execute? Could you or someone please advise me where I have made an error.

```
Sub CreateTable()

Dim ws As Worksheet, tableTopRow As Long, numberRowsFromDropdown As Long
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

'Get the location of your dropdown
Dim rngDropDown As Range
Set rngDropDown = ws.Range("X6")

tableTopRow = 1     'Top row of your table.

'The below range contains the location of drop down @ "X6"


'Set the range of your table
Dim rngTable As Range
Set rngTable = ws.Range("$C10$" & tableTopRow & ":$C20" & numberRowsFromDropdown)

'Create the table
ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rngTable, , xlNo).Name = "Table1"

End Sub
```

Comment: My current format for my drop down menu input is shown below:

https://imgur.com/a/arLuA

When an option is clicked on the drop down menu it changes an input in cell "X6" which then carries an If statement in "Y6" to give the value an input.

https://imgur.com/a/YR1zI

(If statement shown below):
=(IF(X6=1,1,IF(X6=2,3,IF(X6=3,5,IF(X6=4,(10))))))

Sorry for not stating this information above.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Make sure that you read the yellow highlighted portion, as this is important.

Comment: @K.Davis I have applied your reply in the sheets own code, however I still could not get the code to run properly -- nor assign any macros to the drop down menu (if that's even what I am supposed to do)

Comment: You don't have to assign anything to the drop down. This uses the [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel) event, so anytime you select an item from the drop down it automatically runs. But what exactly does the drop down have in it? It's based off just using a number, but if it has anything else in it (such a word like 'years') then I need to know so I can consider that in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add tables using the `Sheet.ListObjects.Add` method.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim Tgt As Range
    Set Tgt = Range("X6")

    If Intersect(Target, Tgt) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Dim tableTopRow As Long, numberRowsFromDropdown As Long
    tableTopRow = 10     'Top row of your table.
    numberRowsFromDropdown = Tgt.Value + tableTopRow - 1

    'Set the range of your table
    Dim rngTable As Range
    Set rngTable = Range("$C$" & tableTopRow & ":$C$" & numberRowsFromDropdown)

    'Delete previous Table, if it's there
    On Error Resume Next
    ListObjects("Table1").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Create the table
    If Tgt.Value > 0 Then
        ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rngTable, , xlNo).Name = "Table1"
    End If

End Sub
```

> **Important**: This uses the `worksheet_Change` event. This means that this code must be placed in your **worksheet's object module**, *not in a standard module*. The easiest way to ensure you are doing this is to exit out of VBE and right-click the worksheet tab, then click View Code. **Also**, you may not change the name of this subroutine, else the event will not fire.

Basically every time you change a value on your worksheet, this event will fire. However, it checks to see if `tgt` intersects with `Target`, and if it doesn't then it will exit the sub.

So your `tgt` is set to `X1` (according to your code, I believe this is your drop down). And the table will be created starting at C10.

Comment: Sam, if you want to show further code, it's best to edit it into your original question, than do it in a comment (very hard to read).

Comment: @ChrisMelville thanks. Deleted previous comment and added it to the original post. Will keep this in mind for next time :)

**added additional content to first post**